# Elegir elemento dentro de un array javascript

Tags: java-swing

// Tengo este array en javascript y quiero elejir la propiedad "id" del ultimo elemento  de forma tal que pueda usarlo como valor numerico

```
tengo un boton em mi DOM que agraga un nuevo elemento atraves del metodo handleAdd agrega un nuevo elemento lo que quiero hacer es que el valor de id del nuevo elemento sea el valor del ultimo elemento del array +1 de forma que sea 123456...

class counters extends Component {
  state = {
    counters: [
      { id: 1, value: 4 },
      { id: 2, value: 0 },
      { id: 3, value: 0 },
      { id: 4, value: 0 }
    ]
  };


  handleAdd = () => {
    let addCounter = this.state.counters.push({ id: {lastid +1}, value: 0 });
    this.setState({ addCounter });
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes obtener la longitud del arreglo con la propiedad **length**

```
const lastId = counters.length;
let addCounter = this.state.counters.push({ id: lastId, value: 0 });
```

Comment: Al obtener counters.length + 1, estás tomando una posición mas de la esperada.

Answer (score 0):

*Recuerda que la posición* **CERO** *no se omite, es decir que si inicias almacenando información en la posición 1 cuando hagas* **Array.length**, *este te va a decir que hay 2 datos. Partiendo de eso si no lo llenas en javascript la primer posición por defecto es* **undefined**.

*Para lo que pides sería hacer lo siguiente:*

```
class counters extends Component {
    state = {
        counters: [
            { id: 0, value: 4 },
            { id: 1, value: 0 },
            { id: 2, value: 0 },
            { id: 3, value: 0 }
        ]
    };


    handleAdd = () => {
        this.state.counters.push({
            id: this.state.counters.length,
            value: 0
        });
       // this.setState({ addCounter 
    });
};
```

*No se para que usas el metodo* **setState(param)**, *pero supongo que si lo que haces es reemplazarle a tu variable global* **state** *el arreglo por el que acabas de modificar, me temo que estas haciendo doble trabajo, ya que en tu metodo* **handleAdd()** *está manipulando dicho arreglo y añadiendole el nuevo objeto.*

*No necesitas hacer lo siguiente:*
**this.state.counters.length + 1**, *porque estarías saltando una posición, es decir, el arreglo quedaría de la  siguiente manera:*

```
[
    { id: 1, value: 4 },
    { id: 3, value: 0 },
    { id: 5, value: 0 },
    { id: 7, value: 0 }
]
```

*Recuerda, la primer posición del arreglo es el index* **CERO**,
*Entonces al hacerle* **.length** *al arreglo que acabo de mostrarte va a retornar* **8 + 1 = 9**.

*Por eso omite el* **+ 1** *y listo espero haber sido claro*

Comment: gracias esto fuciono !

Comment: Con gusto, espero tu voto.